# How to model class `User` having a field `List<User> friends` in FireStore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Cloud Firestore, I have a root collection called 'users':

```
class User {
     String name;
     ...
}
```

Every user in this collection is a document with a document ID. These are stored like

```
root->users->
    userId1->Name:Mark, ...
    userId2->Name:Zuck, ...
    userId2->Name:Erb, ...
```

Should `User` class contain a field `userid` to store the document ID?

These users also have friends:

```
class User {
     String name;
     List<User> friends;
     ...
}
```

How should I model this?

- Should I change my list to `List<String> friendsId`?
- Should I remove `List<User> friends` to outside with another class like

  `class UserFriends{
      User user;
      List<User> friends;
  }`

  and make another 'userFriends' root collection?
- Or any other way.

Comment: I would go with `List<String> friendsId`.

Answer (score 0):

To your first question, yes, you could add the document ID as a field on the Java object. Be careful if you're doing that in combination with [custom object mapping](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data?hl=fa#custom_objects), you might serialize the ID unintentionally.

Your second question seems like it might be a good candidate for [subcollections](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/structure-data#subcollections). You might want to query the user's friendships in different ways, and subcollections make that really easy.

Comment: If I have 10 users being loaded, each with a 5 friends, will that cause 50 queries to be charged to my firestore bill when I'm using subcollections?